# SSL not working when using PROXY-protocol between NGINX-loadbalancer and NGINX-reverse-ssl-terminating-proxy

Tags: nginx, ssl

I've got an issue with our NGINX load balancer (based on the stream-module) and using the real remote IP of our end users.

**Situation**

Our situation includes a lot of servers, but there are two relevant servers:

- Server A -> Load balancer running NGINX with the stream-module
- Server B -> upstream running an NGINX reverse proxy to our relevant application, responsible for SSL-termination

Server A uses SNI to route to various upstreams (using `ssl_preread on`).

I think we want to achieve the following situation:

```
Client ---[HTTPS]---> NGINX LB ---[PROXY PROTOCOL]---> NGINX Reverse proxy incl. SSL-termination ---[HTTP]---> PHP-container
```

**Configuration**

For this specific situation, I've added an additional server block to our stream with a different port, to be able to test this alongside some other projects. The relevant bit of configuration on Server A:

```
stream {
    server {
        listen 4431;
        listen [::]:4431;
        ssl_preread on;
        proxy_pass 172.16.25.4:4431;
        proxy_protocol on;
    }
}
```

As can be seen, port 4431 forwards to our upstream on port 4431, with `proxy_protocol on` so it should use the proxy protoocol here.

On our Server B (upstream `172.16.25.4`) I've got another NGINX-instance which has the following config:

```
server {
    server_name <REDACTED>;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header x-forwarded-proto      https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $proxy_protocol_addr;
    }

    listen 4431 ssl proxy_protocol;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<REDACTED>/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<REDACTED>/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

You see another listen for port 4431, with the `ssl` and `proxy_protocol`-directives. As far as I've understood, this means that the listening server should support the PROXY-protocol-messages coming from our load balancer.

**SSL connection issue**

I'm however not able to establish an SSL-connection. I can understand that would not be possible from Server B (as the client does not use the PROXY-protocol), but I think that it should be possible from Server A though. If I try to connect I get the following response:

```
user@ServerA $ openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:4431 -servername <REDACTED>
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=0
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 320 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

I don't understand why I wouldn't be able to connect using SSL from our load balancer, I reckon (or maybe it's more that I hope) it must be something quite simple I'm missing. Has anyone got an idea on what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing?

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: Well, I'm not too sure what changed, according to the snippets I posted above nothing, but after re-trying it yesterday everything worked as expected, so between our LB and our backends. communication now uses PROXY-protocol as expected, whilst having SSL-termination on the side of the backends.